# Chrome slow opening file upload on network path

Tags: google-chrome, network-shares

I'm getting different behaviors in Chrome vs. Firefox and IE, when trying to upload a file from the same web page.

The first time I click browse, the file open dialog opens immediately.  I upload my first file.  The second time, on Chrome, it hangs for about 5-10 minutes before opening the dialog, while on Firefox and IE, it is always immediate.

This only happens on network paths.  If I switch the path to a local drive, it opens immediately, every time, on every browser.

This is reproducible at will, and occurs 100% of the time.

What is the cause of this and/or how do I fix?

Comment: Some people solved similar problems by clearing the Downloads and Documents folder or the Chrome downloads list.

Comment: Do you have many files in those network paths?

Comment: Could you take a process monitor trace: one for when you're using Chrome and another when you're using FF/IE. I'll take a look.

Comment: I've read that Chrome requires "trust" in order to access network shares. It might be your issue. Add the intranet site to your trusted site list and it might be faster.

Comment: @harrymc, tried that, no help. so far the only variable is whether the path is local or network.

Comment: @LatinSuD, no, very few files, or empty path.

Comment: @BlizzardsGambit, it opens fine the first time, takes 3-10 minutes the next time and each time after.

Comment: Try running a registry cleaner such as CCleaner.

Comment: Which Windows and Chrome versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The thread
[Why is the first download slow to open dialog box?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9M4TwVqVNQQ)
discusses a similar problem :

> The problem occurs, I think, because Chrome has stored a previous
>   save-to location that no longer exists (such as one on a network
>   drive).  I was able to prove this by looking through the samba logs on
>   our old server (which no longer had a shared volume) and I saw
>   repeated attempts to access the old shared volume every time I
>   attempted to save something with Chrome.
>
> The delay was manageable until the old server itself was removed from
>   our network, then the delays stretched to almost a full minute or
>   more.  (The delays were less when the server was still active, because
>   the server presumably told Chrome that there was no such storage
>   location.  But once the server itself was gone, Chrome would wait for
>   an inordinately long timeout on the first "save" of each browsing
>   session.)

A solution that worked for one person was :

1. Within Chrome, Click the Customize icon in the upper right. Choose Bookmarks/Bookmark Manager/Organize.
2. Export your bookmarks to an HTML file -- somewhere you can find it.
3. Close Chrome.
4. Go to
   `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data`
   (fill in your user name)
5. Right click on the `User Data` folder and rename it. I just add an X to the end of the name.
6. Restart Chrome, go to Bookmark Manager and import the bookmarks

Another workaround : Running CCleaner to clean the registry has helped another guy.

Comment: I've tried CCleaner multiple times.  Will try the bookmarks approach and report back.

Comment: This is a procedure to delete all user information, while only saving the bookmarks.

Comment: Yup.  So, tried this procedure, starting with fresh empty User Data folder, pointing to network folder with only 3 files in it, same results.  First open was instant, uploaded file, then tried to open location again, took about 5 minutes to get the open file dialog.  It's still instant for both, for the same location, in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall Chrome, delete all folders (search for "Chrome"), then reinstall?

Comment: Yes, in fact this behavior occurs on my boss's machine, and on a new machine I got a couple weeks ago.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Chrome - try to get help on the Chrome forums.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me directly! Was irritated by this lagging for years,tried everything. And this just worked

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10347775/chrome-taking-a-long-time-to-save-files-locally-system-freeze-for-seconds-before-dialogue-solution?hl=en

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).